# WCSession returns 'unreachable' when watchOS app is in background

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

If Apple iWatch goes into the background, then WCSession gives us `unreachable` which also means that `WCSession.default.isReachable` is giving us `FALSE`.

I am not able to transfer data if the Apple watch is in the background.

```
let applicationData = ["value":"key"]
if let session = session, session.isReachable
{
  WCSession.default.transferUserInfo(applicationData)
}
```